# Turing Machine Decidable: What right does the definition have to say what's not in language L?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of Turing Decidable. The definition goes something like this:

> TM M decides language L iff the strings in L put M into the Accept state
>   and the strings NOT IN L put M into the Reject state

My problem is.. the strings "NOT IN L"? How can the definition be based on what's *not* in L? Shouldn't the definition be more like this?

> TM M decides language L iff the strings L put M into the Accept state
>   or the Reject state.

Then you can divide L into two subsets - those that are accepted, and those that aren't. But they're all *decided* by M, no?

Comment: @RanG. Good point. I'll take out the infinite part. My question still stands though :)

Comment: The problem may be in the phrasing. *M decides language L* is a shorthand for *TM M decides membership of language L*, i.e. it takes an arbitrary string (whether in L or not) and outputs whether the string is in L.

Comment: A language is just a set of words. A machine decides a language if it always correctly determines set membership.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'll convert the comment into an answer)

First, definitions:

$L$ is a language, that is, a set of words where each word has a finite length. If all the words that ever exist are denoted as $\Sigma^*$ then any language is $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$. Words that are not in $L$ are in a different subset we denote $\overline L=\Sigma^*\setminus L$. Both $L$ and $\overline L$ can be infinite (i.e., have infinite many words). Still, each word in $L$ or in$\overline L$ is of finite length.

Now, assume that we have a TM that never goes into an infinite loop (such TMs are called *deciders*). If it never goes into a loop, it means that for any input word, it will either halt and accept or halt and reject.

If we used your second definition, then any $L$ will be $L=\Sigma^*$, since all the words are either accepted or rejected.

So the answer is that the first definition is correct. A decider $M$ (a TM that always halt!) splits the space of all the possible words $\Sigma^*$ into two disjoint subsets, the words that are accepted by $M$, denoted $L(M)$ and the ones rejected by $M$, denoted $\overline{L(M)}$. Again, $\Sigma^*=L(M) \cup \overline{L(M)}$, since every word is either accepted or rejected.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I need to think about this a bit more, but can't right now. I'll get back to it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that M deciding a language meant _all_ words in ∑* would end up on accept or reject. When you said it's called a decider, I thought that was a special kind of TM, not synonymous with a TM that decides a language.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that $M$ makes a decision about every string, but this does not put them in $L$. Your second definition would lead to every (decidable) language being the same (any decider *always* ends up in a Reject or Accept state, so by the second definition every decider would decide every language).

To draw an analogy, take for example the language $English$, and the Turing Machine stand-in $Me$. If you present a word to me, I can decide (hopefully!) whether the word is in $English$ or not, but the words that make me say $No$ are not in $English$ - i.e. the language consists only of the words that are in it, it is *not* two sets (those that make me say $Yes$ and those that make me say $No$).

Going back to the maths, this is what the first definition says, but is a more precise manner appropriate for computability: the TM $M$ decides $L$ if for every string $\omega$ it says $Yes$ if $\omega \in L$ and $No$ if $\omega \notin L$.

Comment: Yeah, meant M. Fixed it

Comment: My question is, if M decides a word with a reject, why is that word not part of the language M decides? Why is that word said to _not_ be in L?

Comment: @yts adjusted the answer a little.

Comment: @yts, try thinking of it this way: $M$ is not deciding a word (because it isn't), $M$ is deciding whether the word is in $L$ or not (as this is what is actually meant). Saying $M$ decides $L$ is a somewhat awkward grammatical shorthand for this.

Comment: Hold on. If a TM decides a language, that means that no matter what word in ∑* you give it, it will always either accept or reject. No word will loop. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: @yts yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ah I got it now. I started getting that with Ran Gs answer, but I wasn't positive. I didn't realize that a machine deciding L means that there are no words which will loop. I was understanding that some words are halted on, and others are not. Those words on which it halts are in the language. Ran G was trying to get me to stop thinking like that. Thanks for your help :) My professor thought I was going crazy

Comment: @yts This is the difference between a decision procedure and a proof procedure.